# Construction 'of' the plant vs Construction 'on' the plant

Tags: prepositions

The following typical sentence uses the preposition **of** :

> Construction **of** the plant began in November 1938, and completed by the following summer

But I've discovered some instances when **on** is used:

> Construction **on** the plant is expected to begin in late summer, and the
>   plant is expected to be open by spring or early summer of 2015.
>   (from [Jackson Sun](http://www.jacksonsun.com/article/20140619/NEWS01/306190020/Auto-parts-maker-build-plant-Jackson?nclick_check=1))

and

> Construction **on** the plant started in the late 1970s. (from [The Steel Industry of China](http://books.google.ru/books?id=O6fc7JgR59cC&lpg=PA4&ots=CnC-1gPAu_&dq=%22construction%20on%20the%20plant%20%2a%20in%22&hl=ru&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22construction%20on%20the%20plant%20%2a%20in%22&f=false))

and

> Construction **on** the Shidao Bay plant began in 2011 but was suspended
>   in the wake of the Fukushima crisis, the China Internet Information
>   Center said. (from [Australia Network News](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-01-05/an-china-resumes-work-on-nuclear-plant/4454054))

Is the use of the **on** preposition a typo or a mistake? 
Or is there some subtle difference in meaning? Could it be a shortening of "construction *work* on the plant started in..."?

In Russian we may only say "construction **of** the plant began in..", so I tend to translate such sentences using **of** only. *On* seems counterintuitive. To start some operation **on** something, one has to have that something present in the first place, yet when a new plant construction project is launched, there is no plant present.

"Construction **on** the plant", when rendered in Russian, would mean adding some facility or building to an already existing plant.

Comment: We often hear reports like "Work *on* the project began in November"  but I can't recall any "construction" equivalent.

Comment: Then I could've stumbled upon an incorrect use of the preposition. I'll remake the question a bit.

Comment: Plenty of occurrences on "construction on the plant began" or "construction on the building began" if we google them. It's clear on [that page](http://thetimes-tribune.com/news/dickson-city-officials-clash-on-new-borough-building-1.1685471) that it is about the beginning of the building itself.

Comment: To me, when I hear construction has begun on  a *site*, I think more of headworks than of the buildings which will follow. 
"On the plant" is similar. It may be a new usage Or legalese, to distinguish successive phases of development. If this relates to a contract, I'd be securing the services of a contract lawyer. Your contractors could even be trying to avoid admitting they haven't started.

Comment: @user42307 - -  'Headworks', meaning, design and planning activities, not work in the physical sense?

Comment: Headworks meaning surveying, ground levelling and drainage, service pipes, anything to ready the site for construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is fundamentally the difference between phrases (where **noun1** is a [verbal noun](https://www.google.com/search?q=verbal+noun)):

- *`noun1`* **of** *`noun2`* (A verbal noun *being part of* an Entity. Relatively more noun-like.)
- *`noun1`* **on** *`noun2`* (A verbal noun *applied or directed to* an Entity.  Relatively more verb-like)

In this case, "of" is being used as follows:

> Define ***of:*** ([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on?q=of))
>
> 6.) Expressing the relationship between an abstract concept having a verb-like meaning and a noun denoting the subject of the underlying verb:
>   *the opinion of the directors*
>   *the decision of the County Council*
>
> 6.1) Where the second noun denotes the object of the underlying verb:
>   *the murder of two boys*
>   *payment of his debts*
>   *an admirer of Dickens*

And "on" is used as follows:

> Define ***on:*** ([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on?q=on))
>
> 5.) Having (the thing mentioned) as a target, aim, or focus:
>   *five air raids on Schweinfurt*
>   *thousands marching on Washington*
>   *her eyes were fixed on his dark profile*

Examples of the noun-like use of **of**:

- X of Y.
- War of 1812.
- Development of Character.
- Analysis of Variance.
- The Battle of Gettysburg.  (In 1863, in the **Battle *of* Gettysburg**, General Lee's initial **attack *on* Union forces** appeared to be a sign of success.)
- Act of Kindness. (This is provided to show that not all forms follow this pattern. In this case, "Kindness" is describing the type of "Act".  "Act" is not a verbal property/relation of "Kindness".)

Examples of the verb-like use of **on**:

- X on Y.
- War on Terror.
- Debate on Immigration.
- Effects on Tourism.
- Agreement on Terms.

There are not as many cases where you can use both "of" and "on".  Consider the following which further demonstrates the differences:

- *Construction **of** the new tower will begin January of next year.*  Focus is construction of the the tower as a whole.
- *Construction **on** the new tower will begin January of next year.*  Focus is on the construction as an activity performed to create the building.
- *payment of his debts*.  This phrase is natural when discussing the full payment. Payment is like a property of his debt, resulting in a *noun-like* meaning.
- *payment on his debts*.  This  might be a partial payment. Payment is an action *applied* to his debt, resulting in a verb-like meaning.

When you can use both "on" or "of", the difference can often be quite small, especially when seen in isolation.  However, a skilled writer might make a *`decision`* **on** *`one over the other`* for subtle rhetoric, style, or other *`distinctions`* **of** *`meaning`*.

---

<sup>Note:  @user42307's fine answer provides a great example of what I mean by a skilled writer choosing a single word for rhetorical purposes!</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the key is to know the *place* where the construction is happening! Or else, the usage of *on or of* is quite clear.

Consider this (without *plant*):

> The construction *of* the **building** has started = They have dug the ground, the iron bars are tied, all the base/pillars are now getting constructed.
>
> The construction *on* the **ground** has started = It's just ground. Now the construction has started *on* it.

**But,** that's not the case here. It's about *[plant](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plant_1)*...

So...

When you start construction *of* plant, you *probably* start from zero.

And if you start construction *on* plant, the plant *probably* exists and you *add something to improve* by further constructing on it. It could be new machinery, new block or the like.

**Now your sentences:**

**The all three** examples you quoted talk about constructing the plants from zero and finishing them at whatsoever period. The only sentence that uses *construction **on*** is I think yours, I mean your own creation which means the plant was getting improved i.e. the plant already existed and some additional construction happened ***on*** it.

Comment: Thanks, Maulik! I could've stumbled upon a typo in Google Books. The use of **on** is rare. I've reworked the question.

Comment: @snailplane, thanks. I was on my mobile. Could not recognized those with T9 language on! :)

Answer (score 1):

As a hardened journalist, I'm used to nipping at the heels of politicians who have something to hide. Usually these people are careful not to actually *lie* - and in the attempt, get entangled in some pretty wobbly English.

If, say, a pollie were asked to justify the allocation of significant sums of money for a production plant which is rumoured never to have even commenced, I can quite imagine certain politicians replying,

"Construction on the plant is expected to begin in late summer."

(That's just 5 seconds before the politician finds a pressing need to leave very quickly in a black limo).
- And just 10 seconds before a horde of journos start yelling for a clarification, and
just 5 days before the particular politician is found to be embroiled in a corruption scandal.

"Construction on the plant" is high up there on my list of "What exactly do you means"... anybody can make a slip of the tongue, a typo, or use a little-known Ozark mountain term. But failing to clarify when asked?

Legal translators know this stuff. Contractors are notorious for trying to solve their cash-flow problems by trying to qualify early for their next financial advance. Wobbly, unorthodox terms will come thick and fast. Frankly, we don't go around talking about "construction on a plant" and get away with it.

When Carter and Sadat were  at Camp David and confronted with Begin's ambiguous English draft agreement, they solved the issue tactfully by asking for a French translation of the Israeli offer, as was their diplomatic right. Since you cannot successfully obfuscate in two languages, the Israelis had to clarify and the  [Egypt-Israel Peace Treaty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_David_Accords) became reality.

CopperKettle, Don't be bullied. Be strong enough in your convictions when you translate so as to demand clarification.

Comment: Thanks for a tip! I'm not being bullied at the moment, just trying to expand my vocabulary. I find asking questions a good way to make a word or expression stick in my mind.